# Protecting Mars with no magnetosphere: Can genetic engineering help?

Tags: physics, hard-science, atmosphere, terraforming, genetic-engineering

It is the year something-something, and the Sol system has been colonized.  The Sun is surrounded by a growing cloud of habitats, Venus is a veritable garden world, Jupiter is being fed mass from the sun so that it may one day turn into a brown dwarf, the Oort cloud is the new frontier, human lifespan is biologically indefinite, and Mars, despite being the least attractive candidate for terraforming, has turned into life-bearing world protected by a superconducting satellite that produces a magnetic field placed in the L1 Lagrange point.

It is a time of wonder and miracles.

Until it isn't.

Something caused the collapse of this civilization, and now only derelicts remain around the sun, the citizens of Earth, Venus and Mars had regressed back to a animalistic state while everyone else died, uploaded themselves into computer banks on Titan, or fled to the Oort cloud, and beyond.

Through out all this, the Satellite above Mars had persevered, keeping to its station like a sentinel of old with a shield of magnetic fields foreve-oh, never mind, got hit with a system wide Kessler syndrome event.  Guess without Mars is doomed...Right?

Essentially, I'm wondering if it is possible to to have a a backup in case such an event where to occur.  It's impractical to start up Mars's core so that's out.  Perhaps having a mixture of genetically engineered life forms to  create a specialized atmosphere more resistant to solar winds?  If so, how?  Are there other alternatives on the table? Do we have to go all Darwin IV on Mars?

Something to get out of the way.

Mars has been partially terraformed, there is a sea of liquid water, the air has been increased, though not to the level of earth's atmosphere and with, to Terrans at least, high levels of carbon dioxide.  Plants and animals have adapted to these conditions.

Edit:

First off, thank you to everyone who has commented so far it really helps.

Now, it appears that I may have been to unclear on what I was asking exactly.  So!  To remedy this, let me give a some more clarification than before.

- The main point of debate is that there is need for a shielding due to the fact that atmospheric lose occurs over geological timescales.  Thing is, the inhabitants of Mars in the setting would evolve into a post human species adapted to the red(?) planet (the bits of blue/violet and greenery ruin the image a bit) and that would take evolutionary timescales i.e. at least a millennia or more.  Now, why have humans gone to such a state, that's a post for another time but suffice to say I have an interest in keeping the atmosphere intact for as long as possible, preferably as when the sun is big enough to non the Earth.
- When I said life on Mars has 'adapted', what I meant to say was 'genetically engineered' then over the millennia grew accustomed to Mars.  This is due to the fact Mars is in reality a very unattractive terraforming candidate for a carbon copy of Earth (Venus, once it was cooled down with mirrors, sped up with targeted comet strikes to produce a more 'normal' 24-ish day/night cycle, jump start it's magnetosphere, change the axial tilt slightly get some seasons in and funnel most of the CO2 and N out of the surface be used in the terraforming process, shipped to Mars, the space habitats or crushed into a sizeable diamond moon with bits of Mercury sprinkled in; the end result is a good candidate for colonizing, though bit on the tropical side;)), thus Mars was terraformed till it was 'good enough', meaning the deepest the deepest body of water is around 1.5-2 kilometers deep, the atmosphere was thickened though not Earths 14.7 psi of atmospheric pressure but enough to cause storms of some concern, so around 9-10 psi if my horrible knowledge of atmospheric science estimation is right.  The life there, along with the human population, was genetically modified to handle lower pressures and the much higher CO2 levels (though the high CO2 levels would give an excuse as to why the colonists turned feral, though not a good one), and have overall better radiation repair, though that was added as a after thought following bureaucracy  and the vocal minority calling "just in case!".  However, life on Mars can live in more extreme conditions, though I would like to keep the conditions as stated above for as long as possible.
- The question I'm asking is there a any way to keep such an atmosphere with without machinery and instead through some biological process, either naturally evolving by coincidence or through genetic engineering?

Thank you.

Comment: u do your numbers [Mars presently loses about 100 grams (a quarter of a pound) of atmosphere every second](https://www.forbes.com/sites/startswithabang/2017/03/03/nasa-discovers-how-mars-lost-its-atmosphere/), which is about 3000t per year.  would say that the number will not depend that much on the density of air at the surface, but one can multiply it by a 100, current atmosphere mass about 2.5e13t, soo if pressure on the surface would be 100kpa, to lose 1 percent of it it will take about 100 million years. plenty of time to die out or crawl back to the technology and space age.

Comment: It's a non-problem. The lack of a magnetic field leads to the loss of atmosphere *over geological time*. Not an issue on human time-scales, not even an issue on historical time-scales. There are only 15,000 years between the invention of agriculture and our present day... and at least one million years is needed for the loss of atmosphere to become measurable.

Comment: As MolbOrg points out, atmospheric loss is something to be concerned about on geological timescales. Also, an atmosphere with the same surface pressure as Earth's will be far deeper than Earth's, making it a very effective radiation shield. Mars just doesn't need a magnetic field. Your "garden world" Venus is in trouble though, since even if you somehow deal with its hellish atmosphere, it'll be reliant on some form of orbital shades and artificial light/heat sources to make it habitable. As support systems fail, it's going to start roasting each 2-month day and freezing each 2-month night.

Comment: You seem to be thinking that the only effect of no magnetosphere is that the solar wind blows the atmosphere away. You seem to be forgetting that the solar wind itself is dangerous and is full of radiation.

Comment: @DKNguyen an atmosphere will block radiation, especially if you pile up enough to have ~1 atm of surface pressure in Mars gravity. Even the existing atmosphere provides a lot of shielding: https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/images/estimated-radiation-dosage-on-mars/

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff Hmmm. I see.

Comment: @Seraphim Per the edit: your characterization of Venus as a better terraforming candidate is...dubious. Turning Mars into a garden paradise would be a good side project to do while you're trying to make Venus barely habitable. And in any case, there's little biology can do other than develop a technological civilization to obtain replacement atmosphere from off-world, and atmospheric loss is slow enough that you could conceivably evolve a new intelligent form of life to build that civilization (mammals have existed for less than 200 million years).

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff I recommend watching the videos "Spring time on Mars", "Winter on Venus", "Terraforming techniques", "Colonizing Venus", "Colonizing Mars" by Isaac Arthur on YouTube.

Comment: @Seraphim I don't. The facts are that Venus needs drastically more severe atmospheric alternation, importation of enormous amounts of hydrogen, and either changes to its rotation that are simply impossible to achieve with anything resembling current technology, or orbital megastructures to shade and reflect sunlight that are only a little more plausible. Terraforming Mars is something close enough to our current capabilities that we can seriously think about it, but terraforming Venus is completely beyond us.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff Rotation can be solved by strategic bombardment of comets from the Oort cloud or outer system to speed up rotation.  This also provides hydrogen though considering stellar lifting is a thing in this setting and shipments of the suns mass, either in cargo hold of some kind or with a particle beam bouncing of magnetic satellites, a hydrogen beam can be aimed at Venus.  Shading would be needed at the beginning to cool Venus and extract the extra atmosphere, but after wards Venus could be stable enough to allow the removal of the shading.  This is optional of course.

Comment: You want the hydrogen to bind up excess oxygen, and the hydrogen in Oort cloud objects is already bound up with oxygen, plus you're adding even more nitrogen...that's really just making things worse. It also has energetic issues...in short, Venus isn't going to be cooling off any while you're doing it, and you may be waiting a while for it to have a stable solid surface again. And you could give Mars deep oceans and a dense atmosphere with a fraction of the impactors in far less time, without having to resort to performing *star-lifting operations on the sun*.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff Well I guess its a matter of perspective.  The terraforming projects occurs in the future so what is feasible now and in the future will be very different.  There are issues with the methods I described yes but I don't of the word count to go into depth on the actual process I imagine.  If you're wondering how I came to such ideas in the first place than I really do recommend the videos I listed before hand.  If nothing else than to explain what they did wrong and propose a better source of terraforming info.  Though conversation is not leading to the question at hand!

Comment: It is not a matter of perspective, but one of physics. It's not one of technology either: just about anything that helps dealing with the issues on Venus will also help with Mars. And in general, I don't recommend *any* YouTube videos as sources for this kind of information. At least check the information with other sources, or run some numbers to validate things like the claims you repeated about changing Venus' rotation. Certainly don't say "here, watch hours of this guy's videos" when someone points out that something makes no physical or logical sense.

Comment: I know.  What helps Venus helps Mars.  And as for the YouTube videos, yea, the majority of such videos are not at all good.  I admit, I'm not a mathematician but after I found the videos I did do a background check on who was running the show, here is the wiki link if your interested https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Arthur.  Anyhow, this has derailed a bit, this question is about Mars, not Venus:)!

Comment: I know who Isaac Arthur is. I've run into other people with bizarre misconceptions based on his videos. No, I'm not going to watch his videos.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff Misconceptions?  Could say a few.  If I have been given inaccurate info I would like to know.  And maybe the misconception's you've heard may be due to a lack of context.

Comment: Suggesting that Venus is a better terraforming target than Mars shows a profound misunderstanding of the scale of the problem. When trying to estimate how many times harder Venus would be to terraform, the question is not what the first digit would be, but how many zeros to put on the end. Nobody who suggests such a thing has the slightest idea what they're talking about, and there is no need to waste any more of my time on their videos.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff He isn't the only on to suggest such things, http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/colonysite.php.

Answer (score 4):

/Plants and animals have adapted to these conditions/

They adapt further!  The difference between low atmospheric pressure and progressively lower atmospheric pressure is a lot less than the difference between living underwater in an ocean and living in a desert.  Earth life pulled off the latter feat.  Over time your Mars creatures can pull off the former.

I could imagine photosynthesizers with robust waxy layers to limit water loss into the low atmospheric pressure.  Perhaps these creatures hang on to the oxygen they form in their tissues just like they hang on to the sugars, so they can use both for subsequent metabolism rather than rely on atmospheric O2.

This would be fine story telling.  There would be the native Martian flora and fauna which in some places would be dying out.  Then there are the adapted forms which are spreading - similar to what was there before but more and different.

Don't forget the adapted Earth life which has formed symbioses with indigenous Mars life!  Could that symbiosis swing the other way?  Remember the Mars life did this whole "lost the atmosphere" thing once before, and got through it.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty @Seraphim!

Answer (score 3):

Building upon MolbOrg's comment, it seems you just have to produce 100g of athmospheric content to counter the effect of solar winds on the athmosphere.

So the old civilisation could have created huge machines that produce gases from the soil.
For example on the poles there could be solid oxide electrolysis process installed that turns the water into hydrogen and oxygen.
Like the [MOXIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Oxygen_ISRU_Experiment) prototype.

Also silica has been [found on mars](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/mer/images/pia09491.html). Which reacts partly to water, when combined with hydrofluoric acid.

Or basically from any other material the old civilisations brought up there. Powered by solar or nuclear fusion, since they seemed to have been pretty advanced.

Comment: Silica can't be turned into water with anything short of nuclear transmutation, and you don't need hydrofluoric acid to get the oxygen out. And MOXIE's for electrolyzing carbon dioxide...you don't need a fancy high temperature solid oxide electrolyte to electrolyze water.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff Silica is silicon dioxide. 
And SiO2 + 6 HF -> H2SiF6 + 2 H20
Sure, you can do something less sophisticated to electrolyze water.

Comment: That's not "turning silica into water", that's producing some water as one product of reacting it with hydrofluoric acid. Where are you going to get that? Fluorine is extremely scarce and itself has to be separated from mineral fluorides, which is even more energy intensive than splitting oxygen from oxides. Worse, the only local source of hydrogen is the existing water ice, making this whole reaction a dead end.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff You are right. I changed the wording. Well the hydrofluric acid could have been brought there in large storage tanks from the old civilisation. Since they terraformed Mars so substantially that plantlife and animals can inhabit it, that doesnt seem like too far of a stretch.

Comment: There's still the issue of fluorine being very scarce, and the fluorine atom in a HF molecule weighs 19 times as much as the hydrogen, more than a whole H2O molecule. You need to transport hydrogen to Mars and split oxygen out of rock...HF is a terrible way to do the former and is unnecessary for doing the latter. You could just import elemental hydrogen to combine with the oxygen to make water, and electrolyze molten rock directly to produce free oxygen (look up molten oxide electrolysis). Then you "just" need to import a few quintillion tons of nitrogen to get an Earthlike atmosphere...

Comment: Sorry, correction: a few quintillion *kilograms*. Only a few *quadrillion* tons. You might import ammonia instead: easier to transport and gets you some of the hydrogen you need along with the nitrogen (3.5 times as much hydrogen per kg NH3 as you get per kg of HF, plus you actually need nitrogen, plus ammonia actually exists in Kuiper/Oort objects).

Answer (score 0):

what you could have a hyper bacteria, which is very light, and floats in the atmosphere, they feed of light, heat, radiation, etc. whichever you want, they are in such numbers that they block solar winds, there could have other bacteria to break down some of the surface to make more of an atmosphere, caves would also be an alternative, just make your fauna be underground mostly, and a failsafe that absorbed the "atmosphere" it already had, and bring it into a refuge, plants get to this tank, and form an ecosystem inside the refuge, you let some survive inside, as well as animals, and close any gas exit, the plant also has a piece for the collection of sunlight, waxy layer to reduce water loss, and possibly get more energy from the sun, and a mix of chemosynthesis, (you could also have a machine for the use of solar winds for pure energy, and the plants adapt thanks to genetic modification to transform more kinds of energy for them to use it)

having a solar wind resistant super forest, which grows a shield, so it creates a cave system, mycelial networks work as a part of this ecosystem, the mycelium here was modified to be much better, and smarter, it grows inside the solar shield, and transforms heat from the sun into energy which is spread through the plants, eolic type energy is used, which can be mostly unaffected material as Martian winds are generally stronger than earth's

the sea can have a new roof of materials, on the surface protecting t from evaporating, also, heat can be turned into energy by the plants, as well as light hitting the surface, the water would be highly oxygenated, creature transform part of the soil on cave roofs into food, and their poop is eaten, by plants, fish etc. they could survive for some time,

sorry for any clutter, I'm a bit tired

Comment: The solar wind doesn't penetrate into the atmosphere, it gets deflected way up at the upper reaches of the ionosphere. You'd be partially shielded from it even in low orbit, even though Mars doesn't have a global magnetic field any more (http://lasp.colorado.edu/~brain/images/induced_more.jpg). You mainly have to worry about UV, and an oxygenated atmosphere will form an ozone layer under the right conditions.